# How can I see a user I just created on MongoDB using "register" function inside "passport" module, within a NodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local-mongoose

I am creating a new user by the following code:

```
try {
    User.register(new User({username : email , email : email , password : password}),  password, (err , user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error happened!" , err);
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json({ err: err });
        } else {
            console.log('success');
            passport.authenticate('jwt')(req, res, () => {
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.json({ success: true, status: 'Registration Successful' });
            });
        }
    });
```

But when I try:

```
console.log("the user is" , User);
```

I get this result:

```
the user is Model { User }
```

And by trying this:
console.log("the username is" , User.username);
I get:

```
the username is undefined
```

Also in the post man I can see this result:

> {
> "success": "New user function model(doc, fields, skipId) {\n      model.hooks.execPreSync('createModel', doc);\n      if (!(this
> instanceof model)) {\n        return new model(doc, fields, skipId);\n
> }\n      const discriminatorKey =
> model.schema.options.discriminatorKey;\n\n      if
> (model.discriminators == null || doc == null || doc[discriminatorKey]
> == null) {\n        Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);\n        return;\n      }\n\n      // If discriminator key is set, use the
> discriminator instead (gh-7586)\n      const Discriminator =
> model.discriminators[doc[discriminatorKey]] ||\n
> getDiscriminatorByValue(model.discriminators,
> doc[discriminatorKey]);\n      if (Discriminator != null) {\n
> return new Discriminator(doc, fields, skipId);\n      }\n\n      //
> Otherwise, just use the top-level model\n      Model.call(this, doc,
> fields, skipId);\n    } created!" }

For this line of the code:

```
    res.status(201).json({ 'success': `New user ${User} created!` });
```

I don't know if an error happens while I am creating a new user and this result is because of that or it's normal responses and I must see the saved user somehow differen?

Also this is my `user.js` file if it helps:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        // required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    roles: {
        User: {
            type: Number,
            default: 2001
        },
        Editor: Number,
        Admin: Number
    },
    refreshToken: [String]
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you log the User which is model

```
console.log("the user is" , User);
```

try to log user with lower case which is the document

```
console.log("the user is" , user);
console.log("the username is" , user.username);
```

Comment: Yeah you right. But your suggestion also doesn't work and says there is no variable `user`.